# Pushing data into regex?

Tags: python, regex, file-io, parallel-processing

I am working on a small project which I call pydlp. It is basically a set of regex signatures that will extract data from a fileobject. And a function that check if extracted data is in fact interesting.

This code is how I perform matching. It is far from optimal, as I have to read the file over and over again.

```
for signature in signatures:
 match = signature.validate(signature.regex.match(fobj.read())))
 if match: matches.append(match)
 fobj.seek(0)
```

Is there a way to perform multiple regex matches on the same file object while only reading the file object content once. The file object can be large, so I cannot put it in memory.

Edit:

I want to clarify why I mean by "pushing data into regex". I recognize that regex has similarities with a finite state machine. Instead of passing the whole data at once to the regex engine, is it possible to push parts of it at a time?

```
while True:
 data = fobj.read(1024)
 if data == "": break
 for signature in signatures:
  match = signature.regex.push_and_match(data)
 if match: matches.append(match)
```

Edit 2:
Removed link, as I removed the project from github.

Comment: Read the file content once and loop through the signatures? It is surefire faster than re-reading the file, and I don't get why you do so.

Comment: What is the nature of the data and the regexes? Is it line-oriented text data? Do the regexes operate on single lines of text or larger units?

Comment: Hi @nhahtdh. I do not like the way I am currently doing it. If I could, I would prefer not to read the whole file content, but to push parts of it into the regex engine, as it is being read(n). I have been thinking of strategies where I use some sort of sliding window to achieve that. But before I do this, I want to see if anyone can propose a better solution.

Comment: @FMc, some regex signatures can be multiline, the ones I've written so far is not. The data is file content, and the files can be huge.

Comment: I mean you can totally do `data = fobj.read(); for signature in signatures: ...`. It should alleviate part of the problem. As for regex on stream, it is not possible unless the regex engine provides you with the facility to detect whether the regex has hit the end of the string (like what Java does with Pattern and Scanner).

Comment: @nhahtdh, yes. That is the obvious :). But the tradeoff is that I still have to load the whole content into memory. I have considered using mmap to make the file object string like, but then I have to re-read the file for every signature. I have updated the question, explaining what I hope is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this sort of text processing with files too large to read into memory is to iterate over the file line by line:

```
regexes = [ .... ]

with open('large.file.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        for rgx in regexes:
            m = rgx.search(line)
            if m:
                # Do stuff.
```

But that approach assumes your regexes can operate successfully on single lines of text in isolation. If they cannot, perhaps there are other units that you can pass to the regexes (eg, paragraphs delimited by blank lines). In other words, you might need to do a bit of pre-parsing so that you can grab meaningful sections of text before sending them to your main regexes.

```
with open('large.file.txt') as fh:
    section = []
    for line in fh:
        if line.strip():
            section.append(line)
        else:
            # We've hit the end of a section, so we
            # should check it against our regexes.
            process_section(''.join(section), regexes)
            section = []

    # Don't forget the last one.
    if section:
        process_section('\n'.join(section), regexes)
```

Regarding your literal question: "Is there a way to perform multiple regex matches on the same file object while only reading the file object content once". No and yes. No in the sense that Python regexes operate on strings, not file objects. But you can perform multiple regex searches at the same time on one string, simply by using alternation. Here's a minimal example:

```
patterns = 'aa bb cc'.split()
big_regex = '|'.join(patterns)   # Match this or that or that.
m = big_regex.search(some_text)
```

But that doesn't really solve your problem if the file is too big for memory.

Comment: I can know what is the minimum and maximum data length a signature will match. If there is no other solution, I am considering a sliding window. Say that the maximum regex match will be 64 bytes. Then I will have to slide with increments of 32 (64/2), and the size of the window is 96 (64+32). I.e.: regex.match(d[0:96]), regex.match(d[32:128]), regex.match(d[64:160]).

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld Sounds reasonable. Sliding window is effectively like processing the file section by section, under conditions where you cannot make very many assumptions about the text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider using `re.findall()` if you don't need match objects but only matched strings? If file is too big you can slice it for parts, as you suggest, but using some overlaps, to miss no regexes (if you know nature of regexes maybe it'll be possible to find out how big overlap should be).